# set size and position for button

Tags: java, swing

There are two buttons

```
    left = new JButton("prev");
    right = new JButton("next");
```

I add them to jframe like this

```
    mainframe.add(left,BorderLayout.WEST);
    mainframe.add(right,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

But there have got height the same as mainframe's height. How to set my own width and height?

And how to set their position(not only in the NORTH,WEST,EAST,SOUTH)?.

Comment: Please see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 6):

> How to set my own width and height

Don't do that, instead just constrain the size using the `NORTH` or `SOUTH` of a `JPanel` that itself is added to the `EAST` or `WEST` of the outer (parent) layout.

Much like this:

[image: Border GUI]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class BorderGUI {

    BorderGUI() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

        JPanel westConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
        // LINE_START will be WEST for l-r languages, otherwise EAST
        gui.add(westConstrain, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JPanel westControls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
        for (int ii=1; ii<3; ii++) {
            westControls.add( new JButton("" + ii) );
        }
        westConstrain.add(westControls, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel eastConstrain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
        gui.add(eastConstrain, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        JPanel eastControls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
        for (int ii=1; ii<4; ii++) {
            eastControls.add( new JButton("" + ii) );
        }
        // show at the bottom
        eastConstrain.add(eastControls, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        gui.add( new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(6,10)), BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BorderGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```