# Hand-coded GUI - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, awt

I'm trying to hand-code a Java GUI using Swing and AWT. I'm using various layouts to try and achieve or something similar to the GUI posted below (it's a mock layout made with Pencil):

[image: Mock Layout - (Made with Pencil)]

What I got so far is this, but can't seem to make it more "polite", appealing and user-friendly as possible.

[image: Java GUI try]

This is the code I have done so far:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public void buildGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hotel TV Scheduler");

                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));

                JPanel chPanel = new JPanel();
                chPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

                JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
                listPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

                JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));


                JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));


                mainPanel.add(chPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                mainPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                mainPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);


                JTable chOneTable = new JTable();
                JTable chTwoTable = new JTable();
                JTable listTable = new JTable();

                JLabel ch1Label = new JLabel("Channel 1");
                JLabel ch2Label = new JLabel("Channel 2");
                JLabel listLabel = new JLabel("List");

                JButton rmvChOneButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");
                JButton rmvChTwoButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");

                chPanel.add(ch1Label);
                chPanel.add(ch2Label);
                chPanel.add(chOneTable);
                 chPanel.add(chTwoTable);
                chPanel.add(rmvChOneButton);                                         
                chPanel.add(rmvChTwoButton);

                listPanel.add(listLabel);
                listPanel.add(listTable);                



                JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title");
                JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("Genre");
                JLabel durationLabel = new JLabel("Duration");
                JLabel actorLabel = new JLabel("Actor");
                JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("Director");
                JLabel rentableLabel = new JLabel("Rentable");
                JLabel synLabel = new JLabel("Synopsis");

                JTextField txtTitle = new JTextField();          
                JTextField txtGenre = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDuration = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtActor = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDirector = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtSynopsis = new JTextField();

                JCheckBox rentCB = new JCheckBox();

                JButton btnAddProg = new JButton("Add Program");

                JList channelList = new JList();
                JList timeList = new JList();

                infoPanel.add(titleLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtTitle);
                infoPanel.add(genreLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtGenre);
                infoPanel.add(durationLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDuration);
                infoPanel.add(actorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtActor);
                infoPanel.add(directorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDirector);
                infoPanel.add(rentableLabel);
                infoPanel.add(rentCB);
                infoPanel.add(synLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtSynopsis);
                infoPanel.add(btnAddProg);
                infoPanel.add(channelList);
                infoPanel.add(timeList);


                frame.add(mainPanel);
                frame.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

It doesn't have to be exactly as the mock layout shown above but as much as possible similar or at least more user-friendly.

I want to use anything but GridBagLayout and SwingLayout.

Any ideas on how to improve the code and make it look more similar?

Any help is appreciated.

Brian

Comment: Learn GridBagLayout. It will really help things out here. I know its difficult, but bite the bullet.

Comment: Actually it's a school assignment and we were requested not to use it for the simple reason you can find GUI creators that use GridBagLayout.

Comment: Sigh... My recommendation is to then nest layouts as much as you need to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Good luck. If it's supposed to be resizable then that's going to be really hard. If not then you can try to build it entirely with `JPanels` with `FlowLayout` so you can tell the Components how big they should be. Of course you don't have to use any LayoutManager at all. You could arrange every piece with `setBounds()` but that's not much fun. I don't have the time right now but maybe I'll do something with FlowLayouts later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It's licensing is very inclusive:

> MigLayout is free to use for commercial and non-commercial projects and the source code is provided. It is licensed under the very free BSD or GPL license, whichever you prefer

The [JNLP demo application](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp) should show up great examples and corresponding source.

Also, try to avoid nesting logically unrelated components. Getting alignment, borders and padding becomes quite painful as you increase the degree of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

What that GUI mostly needs is:

- White space between components.  Two common ways to provide that are:

  1. Layout padding provided in the constructor of the layout.
  2. Adding an [`EmptyBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) to components or containers.  In the case of many components that already have borders, it is best to wrap them in a `JPanel` and add the border to the panel.
- Constraining panels.  E.G.  If it is desired to have a group of components in the `WEST` of a `BorderLayout` to be 'shoved to the top', add them inside another panel with a `BorderLayout.NORTH` layout/constraint 1st.  Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065192/418556) of what I mean. 

  [image]

Comment: @mKorbel I'm still wondering where all the *"real LayoutManager guru(s)"* are hiding on this one.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse and [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). You can go back and "hand code" specific parts later and still return to WindowBuilder if you like.

Comment: Netbeans used to have a very decent GUI builder (not sure if it still has it). Intellij IDEA also has one but I think it's only for the paid version.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this sample program, will this do to satisfy your needs :-)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TVSchedule
{
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static TVSchedule tvSchedule;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HOTEL TV SCHEDULE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        //centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 5));
        centerPanel.add(createChannelOnePanel());
        centerPanel.add(createChannelTwoPanel());
        centerPanel.add(createListPanel());
        centerPanel.add(createInformationPanel());

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setOpaque(true);
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.RED.darker());
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");
        bottomPanel.add(exitButton);

        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createChannelOnePanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        String[] columnNames = {
                                    "Time",
                                    "Title"
                               }; 
        Object[][] data = {
                            {"01:00","Cowboy and Alchemist."}
                          };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };                      

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        , "Channel 1"
                        , TitledBorder.CENTER
                        , TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));      
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc);     

        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Selected");
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(removeButton, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createChannelTwoPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        String[] columnNames = {
                                    "Time",
                                    "Title"
                               }; 
        Object[][] data = {
                            {"02:00","Grey's Anatomy"}
                          };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };                      

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        , "Channel 2"
                        , TitledBorder.CENTER
                        , TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));      
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc);     

        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Selected");
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(removeButton, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createListPanel()
    {       
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        String[] columnNames = {
                                    "Genre",
                                    "Title",
                                    "Duration (Hours)"
                               }; 
        Object[][] data = {
                            {"Comedy","C & A", "1.5"}
                          };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };                      

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        , "List"
                        , TitledBorder.CENTER
                        , TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc); 

        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 30)), gbc);    

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createInformationPanel()
    {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        , "Information"
                        , TitledBorder.LEFT
                        , TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("TITLE : ");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(titleLabel, gbc);

        JTextField titleField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(titleField, gbc);

        JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("GENRE : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(genreLabel, gbc);

        JTextField genreField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(genreField, gbc);

        JLabel durationLabel = new JLabel("DURATION : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(durationLabel, gbc);

        JTextField durationField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(durationField, gbc);

        JLabel actorLabel = new JLabel("ACTOR : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(actorLabel, gbc);

        JTextField actorField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(actorField, gbc);

        JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("DIRECTOR : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(directorLabel, gbc);

        JTextField directorField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(directorField, gbc);

        JLabel rentLabel = new JLabel("RENTABLE : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(rentLabel, gbc);

        JCheckBox rentCBox = new JCheckBox(" ", false);
        rentCBox.setOpaque(true);
        rentCBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        rentCBox.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(rentCBox, gbc);

        JLabel synopsisLabel = new JLabel("SYNOPSIS : ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(synopsisLabel, gbc);

        JTextArea synopsisArea = new JTextArea(10, 5);
        synopsisArea.setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());
        synopsisArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        synopsisArea.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        panel.add(synopsisArea, gbc);

        JButton addProgramButton = new JButton("Add Program");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 8;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        panel.add(addProgramButton, gbc);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(00.15, 00.15, 60.00, 00.15));
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 8;      
        panel.add(spinner, gbc);

        bottomPanel.add(panel);
        return bottomPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                tvSchedule = new TVSchedule();
                tvSchedule.createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I really don't know what you using between `JButton` and 'JSpinner', that's why never added anything there, hope you can do that yourself.

Here is the output for the same :

[image: HOTEL TV SCHEDULE]